# How to get a copy from a rendered element in canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas

How to copy a drawn element and paste it inside canvas in another position?

```
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
function draw(){
   ctx.moveTo(0,0);
   ctx.lineTo(100,100);
   ctx.lineTo(150,200);
   ctx.stroke();
}
function copy(){
   //.............
}
```

I need a function that can copy a part of drawing in canvas on defined coordinates.

Also, how can I set groups of drawings on packs?

Comment: Please give us more information. More code and where do you fail currently?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/drawImage can draw a canvas on itself. But you may just want to call twice your drawing method after translate your context.

Answer (score 0):

You may use transforms. Also: do not forget to use `ctx.beginPath();`

```js
document.getElementById("canvas");
const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
let cw = canvas.width = 300,
  cx = cw / 2;
let ch = canvas.height = 300,
  cy = ch / 2;


function draw(){
   ctx.beginPath();
   ctx.moveTo(0,0);
   ctx.lineTo(100,100);
   ctx.lineTo(150,200);
   ctx.stroke();
}

draw();


function copy(x,y){
ctx.save();
ctx.translate(x,y)
draw();
ctx.restore()
}

copy(50,10);
```

```css
canvas{border:1px solid;}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: don't save and restore just for a translate... call `translate(-x,-y)`, you'll save trees or even `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0)` if you're sure to go back to original origins.

Comment: ["When you perform a transformation, the entire context’s coordinate system is transformed. After transforming, you often want the coordinate system to be back to normal for your next step. Reversing the transformation by using another transformation is a dicey affair and can easily introduce small errors that add up quickly. "](https://html5.litten.com/understanding-save-and-restore-for-the-canvas-context/)

Comment: That's why I mentioned the absolute `setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);` which will always reset to the default. *save* and *restore* will grab **all** the settable properties of your context, this has a **big** impact on memory. While there might be rounding issues even with translate, if you deal only with ints, you'll be fine, and if you use only `setTransform` you'll be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Well, one simple way would be to copy part of the canvas as an imageData, and copy that to some other part of the canvas:

```
function copy(){
    var imageData = ctx.getImageData(0,0,150,200);
    ctx.putImageData(imageData,250,0);
}
```

This will draw everything in the specified area again at the coordinates specified in ctx.putImageData, including things that were drawn before draw() was called. It also ignores transparency, so the copy will simply replace already existing backgrounds or similar instead of replacing them.

Another option is to render the things you want to copy to an invisible canvas, and then draw that to the main canvas:

```
var tempCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
var tempCtx = tempCanvas.getContext("2d");

tempCtx.beginPath();
tempCtx.moveTo(0,0);
tempCtx.lineTo(100,100);
tempCtx.lineTo(150,200);
tempCtx.stroke();

drawTo(0,0);
drawTo(250,0);

function drawTo(x,y){
    ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,x,y);
}
```

This also works with transparency, so the drawing you copy doesn't have to be rectangular and still can be copied without erasing parts of the background. You can even paste the image in different sizes:

```
function drawTo(x,y,scale){
    ctx.drawImage(tempCanvas,x,y,tempCanvas.width*scale,tempCanvas.height*scale);
}
```